# Python setuptools: how to call function on import but not when run from script?

Tags: python, setuptools

I wanted only one file `pysome.py` to be used as

`import pysome`

and in the console

`$ pysome`

In the latter case I don't want a function to be called,
in the former case I do.

I had

`entry_points={'console_scripts': ['pysome=pysome:main']}`

in setup.py. I tried

`if __name__ != '__main__:
   some_fun()`

but `__name__` turned out to be `pysome` even if called as script.

Then I tried making a package

`setup.py
pysome
  __init__.py
  __main__.py
  pysome.py`

and changed the `setup.py` to

`entry_points={'console_scripts': ['pysome=pysome.__main__:main']}`

In `__init__.py` I have

`from .pysome import *
some_fun()`

and in `__main__.py` just

`from .pysome import *`

but when running `pysome` from console `some_fun()` still gets called.

In the package case the question would be:
How to import `pysome` in `__main__.py` without importing `__init__.py`?
But the solution without package would be nice, too.

Python 3.6 is used.

Comment: Mind if I ask what the use case here is?

Comment: I expected such a question. Suffice it to say, that programming, like life, does not run short of circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

#### introducing a shim

The cleanest solution that comes to my mind is introducing an entrypoint shim function that will pass the call type information to the main function. Something like

```
# pysome.py

def main(called_from_cli=False):
    if not called_from_cli:
        print('imported')
    else:
        print('called from cli')


def _entrypoint_main():
    main(called_from_cli=True)
```

Change the entry point to `_entrypoint_main` in setup script:

```
entry_points={'console_scripts': 'pysome=pysome:_entrypoint_main'}
```

Call `pysome.main()` from code as usual. If you want to sort out the case of calling `pysome.main(called_from_cli=True)`, you can introduce a global flag instead of a function arg and switch it on and off in the shim.

#### extracting frame info

You can also inspect the caller module - if it is the `pysome` script, then `main()` is called from cli. However, I think `inspect` behaviour differs on different interpreters, not sure whether this is the case here.

```
import inspect
import os


def main():
    frame = inspect.stack()[1]
    module = inspect.getmodule(frame[0])
    if module and os.path.basename(module.__file__) == 'pysome':
        print('called from cli')
    else:
        print('imported')
```

#### `pkg_resources` check (not recommended)

I guess you could also check in `main()` whether `pkg_resources` was imported before calling `main()`:

```
# pysome.py
import sys

def main():
    if 'pkg_resources' in sys.modules.keys():
        print('called from command line')
    else:
        print('called from code')
```

but of course this will only work while you don't use `pkg_resources` in your code, so calling

```
import pkg_resources
import pysome

pysome.main()
```

will break the check. This makes things highly breakable and I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: You answer looks good and at first I thought one of the solutions could work, but none does. The problem is that, before calling main(), the module needs to be imported and thus `some_fun()` (from my example) is called. Python has established a way to distinguish the call circumstance by changing `__name__`, but `Setuptools` seems to not have carried that over and it did not establish another method either.

Comment: Invoking code on package/module import won't work with entry points the way you want it to; you have to move the `some_fun()` call inside `main()`. Btw it's [not the best idea to run complex logic on import anyway](https://www.benkuhn.net/importtime).

Comment: When importing in `ipython`, I want the module readily usable, i.e. initialization done, but when the user calls from CLI with --help, I would like to do without initialization.

Comment: If you need the check on package/module level, then neither shim nor `inspect` solutions will apply (afaik the call stack on module level always points to importlib, so inspecting the call stack is useless). The `pkg_resources` check will work on module level, but again, only until `pkg_resources` were not imported in code.

Comment: What about dropping the entry points entirely and resoring to the old way of packaging scripts via `scripts` keyword? Of course, you will have to supply the `pysome` script yourself, thus having two source files instead of one (`pysome` script and `pysome.py` module), but then you have the full control over the script and can put any init logic there.

Comment: That is what I did: `scripts = ['pysome.py'], py_modules = ['pysome']` and no `entry_points`.